# jplayer-preload issue

Tags: jquery, html, jplayer

I am working with HTML5 jPlayer and playing audios through a recursive method.

Everything is going and audio is playing, but there is a delay when it loads the new audio. I want this delay between audios to be removed by preloading the the next audio.

This is what I'm doing in recursion

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("destroy");
if(val > 1)
            {
            
            $("#content #suraname").remove(); 
            $("#content #bismillah").remove(); 
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({ready: function () {$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: "http://www.cityislam.com/Audio/Script/"+qariName+"/"+value_xml_audio+"-"+val_xml+".mp3"});
                                                                $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play");}  })
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer( "option", "cssSelector");
                
            
            }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

From [official documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option-preload):

> The jPlayer constructor option jPlayer({preload) is used to control
>   when jPlayer begins downloading new media. Some browsers will begin
>   the download for the whole media when the preload option is
>   "metadata". Others will require that "auto" is used. The only way to
>   ensure download does not begin automatically is to use the preload
>   option "none". Remember that, the media may not download as it depends
>   on the browser you are using. Mobile browser such as Mobile Safari on
>   iOS 4.2 require a gesture before any media is downloaded or played.
>   ie., The user must press a button to initiate the load or play
>   operations the 1st time.

Comment: sir i want audio  to be loaded before playing 
and it could only load once the first ends ..
the audios are actulayy linked with each other and should sync without any delays

Comment: I probably misunderstood. Take a look here - http://groups.google.com/group/jplayer/browse_thread/thread/bb65740673c1e599

Answer (score 1):

you need to instantiate two separate jPlayers instances, both with `preload: auto` set. Then set the second jPlayer to begin playing in the `ended` event of the first.